# PHPMailer not getting executed via CRON, but working via the browser. What can be the problem?

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer

I am trying to run PHPMailer via cron but for some reason, only the part for the token update is executed after that nothing is executed. But, if I run it via browser everything works fine. Any reason why this happens?

```
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/test/mail/PHPMailer.php");
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/test/mail/SMTP.php");
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/test/mail/Exception.php");
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/test/db/conn.php");

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

Only this part of the code is executed via cron, but in the browser, everything is executed even after this part of the code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE mail_status = 0 LIMIT 100";

$results = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

$salt = rand(5, 20);
$token = sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1(rand(5, 20))));
$insert = "UPDATE customers SET token = '" . $token . "' WHERE id = '" . (int)$row['id'] . "'";
$conn->query($insert);

}
```

This part is not executed via cron:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'example.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = 'example@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'example';
$mail->setFrom('example@example.com', 'example');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'example';
$mail->AltBody = 'example';
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('image/3.jpg', 'logo', '3.jpg');

$result = $conn->query($sql);

foreach ($result as $row) {

$encoded_user_id = base64_encode($row['id']);
$link = "http://www.example.com/test/unsubscribe.php?id=". $encoded_user_id ."&token=".$row['token'];
$body = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body .= '<div><a style="text-decoration: none;color:#38aa20;" href="'.$link.'">unsubscribe</a></div>';
$mail->msgHTML($body);
  try {
      $mail->addAddress($row['email']);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'Invalid address skipped: ' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . '<br>';
      continue;
  }
  try {
      $mail->send();

      echo 'Message sent to :' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . '<br>';

      $update = "UPDATE customers SET mail_status = 1 WHERE id= '" . (int)$row['id']  . "'";
      $conn->query($update);

  } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo 'Mailer Error (' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br>';
      $mail->smtp->reset();
  }
  $mail->clearAddresses();
}

$conn->close();
```

**UPDATE**

Problem solved

Comment: You're going to have to do some troubleshooting to find out what's going on. Use logging/echoes/var_dumps along the way to see how far it gets and what certain variables are.

Comment: your cron task is certainly calling php with cgi, and, with browser, you're certainly calling php with apache config. try to add phpinfo() on the beginning of the file to be sure that the same php.ini is called.

Comment: Web and Cron are different contexts, run by different users, so you probably have a permission or ownership problem.

Comment: @Synchro i have second cron at same direcory that work without problem

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant its is same i tried

Comment: As @aynber said, put in some echo statements to confirm exactly where your code is stopping. Run it manually as the user that runs your cron job.

Comment: @Synchro running from browser manually full code is executed email is send and everything else is working but if cron run it dont send emails

Comment: So do what I said and you’ll find out why.

Comment: @synchro what you mean by " Run it manually as the user " ?

Comment: Run the script your cron job runs, as the user that cron runs it as - if it’s run as root, permission and ownership problems may not show up.

Comment: I don't understand how to run it as user , you mean from shell console ? Because I set a cron from cPanel atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with image , must be set full path to the image

this cause error

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('image/3.jpg', 'logo', '3.jpg');
```

Fix

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage(dirname(__DIR__).'/test/image/3.jpg', 'logo', '3.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Set full path to these files

```
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/test/mail/PHPMailer.php");
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/test/mail/SMTP.php");
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/test/mail/Exception.php");
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/test/db/conn.php");
```

like this

```
require_once("/var/www/_my_path_/test/mail/PHPMailer.php");
```

Comment: this is not the issue because require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/test/db/conn.php"); is loaded and 1st part of code is executed